# Can 2 unrelated webpages be brought together to make 1 webpage whilst keeping their styling?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver

I have 2 sets of website files, the 1st has provided me with the majority of my site (home, about, navigation etc). I have a blog page from the 2nd but would like to use the navigation scheme from the 1st, how do I combine these? Many thanks

Comment: Please start by showing us some code, and telling us what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi Ryan Gee thanks for your reply, as they are, they're just 2 seperate pages & folders as I've been unsuccessful with them up to now. I have tried pasting the HTML from 1 into the other and then doing similar with the CSS code into the main CSS files.

Basically what I gather is happening is that when pasting the main content and corresponding CSS into the main files it is knocking all the positioning, size & colour of the navigation scheme of the other significantly, I guess that CSS code is overriding the other when I don't want it to, it's just the navigation that's causing the problem.

Comment: It sounds like it's just a case of picking the bits you want to keep from each of the files, and manually merging the two. It's going to be very difficult to help further without seeing some code - you can add it to your original question, or create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to migrate your blog to the first website or just mimic that site's navigation on the blog? An easy solution would be to copy the .css file from the first page into your directory for the second page rename it and call it in the head of your html like this

```
<link href="your_main_site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="your_second_site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then make sure there are no conflicts with the id's you have applied, the html will pull styles from both .css files as they are called for in the page. Be sure you're not using the same id or class labels for the nav objects on both style sheets because the first instance will be the only one applied.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply, I would like to bring the blog page in as extra page on the original site, therefore consistent navigation across the site is what I'm aiming for. 

It's all fine until I try to put the blog content in and what happens is the original site navigation gets all skewed or the blog content looses all it's formatting. I've been trying to remove relevant css code from the blog stylesheets as I can see there may be a conflict with it's previous navigation etc and my sites navigation, but no joy so far.

I will give your answer a try